# How to reference mockito within tycho?

Tags: java, maven, mockito, tycho

I'm currently trying to get my build (~30 bundles) done by tycho.
I faced some confusing problems when using [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) in my unit tests.
I created an `eclipse-test-plugin` as fragment project to the tested bundle.
Since tycho should resolve the required bundles using the manifest, I removed the dependency to mockito from the `pom.xml`.
When I then try to add mockito to the required bundles in the manifest mockito isn't listed.
I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269703/resolving-dependencies-with-tycho) and created a target platform pointing to eclipse indigo.
I included the platform specifics so I don't need the eclipse delta pack. Then the first strange thing occurs. Eclipse is telling me that there are some unsatisfiably dependencies and when I set the newly created target platform as active within eclipse, no more packages like `org.osgi.framework`, etc. can be resolved by eclipse. But when I build an `eclipse-product` using tycho and the target platform it is working.

[image: My target-platform]

If I set the current eclipse installation as active platform the bundles are resolved. I've selected the following of the indigo release:

- Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources
- Equinox Target Components
- Jetty Target Components

So my first question is *"What is wrong with my target-platform so that tycho is able to use it but eclipse isn't?"*

To get closer to my original problem (getting mockito running) I set the current eclipse installation as the active target platform. Eclipse then can resolve the `org.osgi.framework` package and others.
I added then the previously removed dependency to mockito again to my `pom.xml` like in the above-mentioned post. But I still can't find mockito when I try to add it to the required bundles in the manifest.

So my second question is *"What am I doing wrong? How do you reference bundles that are not published at the eclipse update site, e.g. the maven central repository?"*

**Update:** During my research I found two ways of including bundles from *non-p2-update-sites* in my target-platform:

1. **Nexus Pro**
   *The professional version of Nexus supports p2-Proxy repositories which can wrap default maven repositories like the Maven Central Repository into a p2 update-site, but the professional version costs round about $800 per year.*
2. **Create an eclipse-repository**
   *You can create a new maven project with packaging* `eclipse-repository` *including all your desired bundles. The created artifact is then deployed to a common web server.*

In your target-platform you can then reference the Nexus p2-proxy repo or the web hosted p2-repo.
Does anyone know other ways - probably more convenient/less expensive?

Please help me understand the confusing world of tycho a bit more...
Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has too many open ends - you should consider limiting it to one question, e.g. "how to reference Mockito with Tycho?"

Comment: I have added an answer to a similar question listing new and elegant way of creating an Eclipse repository in a highly automated and clean manner via `p2-maven-plugin` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24777560/464590

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If mockito isn't in your target platform (and you don't have it in a p2 repository), the easiest thing to do is probably to re-add the dependency back into your pom (without removing the mockito import from your manifest).

I think you'll also need to specify the following in the pom, in the configuration for the target-platform-configuration plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

See the instructions on [adding a dependency on a pom-first artifact](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts). (I'm not sure whether you'll need to specify the resolver).

Regarding support for p2 repositories in Nexus, my understanding is that the p2 plugin for Nexus has since been open-sourced:

- [Nexus - P2 Repository Plugin](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+P2+Repository+Plugin)
- [Nexus - Bundle Maker](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+Bundle+Maker)
- [Github repository for nexus-p2-repository-plugin](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-p2-repository-plugin)