# Maven error "Cannot resolve project dependencies:" -- "org.eclipse.jst.web_sdk.feature.feature.group"

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, maven, dependencies

I was following the instructions at [Import into Eclipse and Set up Development Environment](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse#import-into-eclipse-and-set-up-development-environment) when I got to the step that says

> 2. Run the setup.sh script if you havn't created the target platform: sh setup.sh.

It is to be run in terminal on macOS.

I received the following error messages:

> [ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
>
> [ERROR]   Software being installed: com.amazonaws.eclipse.devide raw:1.0.0.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> [ERROR]   Missing requirement: com.amazonaws.eclipse.devide raw:1.0.0.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):1.0.0-SNAPSHOT requires 'org.eclipse.jst.web_sdk.feature.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
>
> [ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: com.amazonaws.eclipse:com.amazonaws.eclipse.devide:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/shinehah/git/aws-toolkit-eclipse-java-ee-and-report/releng/com.amazonaws.eclipse.devide/pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException

It looks like I need to add "org.eclipse.jst.web_sdk.feature.feature.group" as a dependency, but I'm not able to find that module to download.

This is what is in the pom.xml file originally:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.amazonaws.eclipse.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>com.amazonaws.eclipse.devide</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is the pom.xml file after I added content to it:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws.eclipse</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.amazonaws.eclipse.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>com.amazonaws.eclipse.devide</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws.eclipse</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.jst.web_sdk.feature.feature.group</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is a screenshot of the Project Explorer in Eclipse. I don't have any projects, just this workspace.

[image: Project Explorer pane]

This is the pane titled "Markers" at the bottom of the Eclipse IDE:

[image: Markers pane]
What do I need to do to successfully run "sh setup.sh" as the step instructs?

Comment: Can you provide more details with maven pom.xml and also mention about the type of project.

Comment: I will include the contents of the pom.xml file before and after I altered it. I haven't even created a project yet. When I opened Eclipse, I saw a lot of errors in the Project Explorer.

Comment: @Sambit Ok. I've added the contents of the pom.xml in the original post, as well as screenshots of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This project is different from other project. it is an eclipse plugin project. First of all, after cloning this project, go to command prompt pointing to the directory of this plugin project and run the following command.

`mvn clean package`.

Once the build is successful, import as plugin project in eclipse. This is the normal way of importing eclipse plugin project. It is recommended to go through the ReadMe.md file in the github link. https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-eclipse

I will suggest, first go through the following helpful links about tycho and how to configure and develop eclipse plugin.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Developing_Tycho
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

You can also refer to the following stackoverflow link.

[Dependencies from pom.xml not considered by Eclipse in Tycho Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476451/dependencies-from-pom-xml-not-considered-by-eclipse-in-tycho-project)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll do that. I did make the mistake of installing Maven using Gradle. I think I installed over it afterwards using the recommended method.

Comment: You're asking me to do what I've already done. I had already imported AWS Toolkit to Eclipse right before I got to the step that generated errors.

Comment: Eclipse plugin project is bit different from other project. Chck this link. http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fimport_wizards%2Fimport_plugins.htm

Comment: The problem arises before I get to that step. I have to find the module "org.eclipse.jst.web_sdk.feature.feature.group".

Comment: I am not able to successfully package the files with Maven because I am missing that component.

Comment: You have to use Eclipse JEE , then you have to include this org.eclipse.jst.web_sdk plugin.

Comment: Yes. I am using Eclipse JEE. How do I include the org.eclipse.jst.web_sdk plugin? I am not able to package the software that has the plugin. Let me try.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. It won't find that plugin.